# LWJGL OpenGL glbegin and stuff deprecated

Tags: java, lwjgl

Can I still use those methods in the future? Also, if not, can anyone recommend some good tutorials for modern OpenGL in lwjgl? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LWJGL 'deprecated' just means it's old, I really doubt glBegin is going to be removed as it is used for other drawing functions such as Display Lists, its a good functions for beginners to learn in my opinion.

From my experience in looking for "good" tutorials of advanced topics it's very rare to find one that doesn't have knowledge prerequisites, e.g talking to you with jargon. I can only suggest looking hard on Google and Youtube and practicing , you'd be looking for Vertex Buffer Object and Display List tutorials.(sometimes it's impossible to just find a "good" tutorial and you have to go through the whole process of learning and dedicate a lot of time)